# Multi-modal Input Tensorflow Save and Restore

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save and restore a multimodal model. I am training a neural network with multi-modal input such as the following.

```
    for k, dtype in self.dtypes_x.items():  # structure the data
        self.F += 1
        if dtype == "CATEGORY":  # categorical data (str, int, bool)
            input_els.append(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32))
            x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(n+1, 1)(input_els[-1])  # takes only 999 size
            e = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
            self.F += n
        elif dtype == "NUMBER":  # continuous data (float, int)
            input_els.append(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32))
            e = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(input_els[-1])  # TODO verify int cont. works like this
        elif dtype == "STRING":  # textual data (str)
            input_els.append(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
            encoder = bert.NETWORK(h_params, Y.shape[-1])
            e = encoder(input_els[-1])
        encoded_els.append(e)

    x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(encoded_els)  # layers are now merged
```

As you can see, its just a list of 1D arrays (from a pandas DataFrame) as input instead of list of 2D arrays which are merged. See model.fit(), below, for more information,

```
r = model.fit(
    x=[x[k].values[:N_TRAIN] for k in d_params["x"]],
    validation_data=([x[k].values[N_TRAIN:] for k in d_params["x"]], y.values[N_TRAIN:]),  # TODO: shuffle if using indexing
    y=y.values[:N_TRAIN],
```

When I save it using `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()` and try to restore it using `tf.keras.models.load_model()` I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 128, in explain_lime
  model = s3_get_keras_model()
File "app.py", line 160, in s3_get_keras_model
  return tf.keras.models.load_model(f"/tmp/model")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/save.py", line 205, in load_model
  return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 143, in load
  keras_loader.finalize_objects()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 644, in finalize_objects
  self._reconstruct_all_models()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 663, in _reconstruct_all_models
  self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 709, in _reconstruct_model
  config, created_layers={layer.name: layer for layer in layers})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1283, in reconstruct_from_config
  process_node(layer, node_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1231, in process_node
  output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 977, in __call__
input_list)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1115, in _functional_construction_call
  inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 848, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
  return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 888, in _infer_output_signature
  outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 117, in call
  raise ValueError('A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.')
ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.
```

I did a lot of research particularly on which referred me to try different versions of `keras/tf` loading methods. Nothing seems to work, but I think it is just because it is not-sequential model so I need to pass signatures or something? I tried and that didn't work for me.

Right now all I am using is a single text input column and single numerical output. I am shocked that it was so difficult to find that this is not a common question. What the heck is going on? Please help me, people lives depend on this answer.

Comment: It looks like you're already using the Functional API. What is `encoded_els`? `concatenate` requires a list of inputs.

Comment: its just e. i had typo when redacting

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error with trace, not just the last error?

Comment: added full traceback

Comment: Can you also update your question with how you pass inputs to your model? Along with the `.fit()` call?

Comment: certainly. its just pandas data frame with columns passed in as 1D arrays. see above.

Comment: When you say after you reload the model, is this error immediately after loading or after trying to run fit? You my need to put `encoded_els` in square brackets to make it a list (even though it already is one).

Comment: i am not using the fit function at all. I am using the .predict() but it seems that the error happens on loading the model itself.